# Detecting specific string whether in start, middle or end of a string with Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, string, search

I've been reading some Q&A about regular expressions but I haven't found that answer my question. I'll be using ra as the searched string.

My problem is that I want to find the string 'ra' in any string, 'ra' will be replaced with 'RA', but the thing is that I just want to replace 'ra' as long is not part of any other word, for example: order_ra replaced to order RA but camera cannot be replaced with cameRA.

I tried all ready with `[\s|_]ra(?:[\s|_])` and does not work, because is looking for anything like order_ra or order ra with an space at the end. I would like to match order ra or order_ra either it has a white space after it or not. Can anyone help me on this? I'm not too literate with regular expressions.

The reason I'm needing this is because I want to capitalize 'ra' dynamically in a string sent by a user interaction but not if belong to a word like came**ra** or **ra**dical. I don't know if I explain myself clearly, excuse me if I'm not.

Comment: I think what you meant was: `(?:\s|_)ra(?:\s|_)`

Comment: Yes, thank you Jacob, but either way has the same outcome, at least testing it with RegexBuilder and or with php function preg_replace().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you would use word boundaries: `\bra\b` only matches `ra` on its own, not inside a word. Unfortunately, the underscore is treated as an alphanumeric character, so `index_ra` would not be matched.

Therefore you need to implement this yourself. Assuming that your regex dialext supports Unicode and lookaround assertions, use

```
(?<!\p{L})foo(?!\p{L})
```

This matches `foo`, but not `foobar` or `bazfoo`:

```
(?<!\p{L}) # Assert that there is no letter before the current position
foo        # Match foo
(?!\p{L})  # Assert that there is no letter after the current position
```

If you can't use Unicode character classes, try this:

```
(?<![^\W\d_])foo(?![^\W\d_])
```

This is a bit contorted logic (triple negative for teh win!): `[^\W\d_]` matches a letter (= a character that is not a non-alphanumeric character and not a digit or underscore), so the negative lookaround assertions make sure that there are no letters around the search string ("not a not a (non-alphanumeric or digit or underscore)"). Twisted but necessary since we also want start and end of the string match here.

Comment: Awesome! thanks for the explanations, will help me understanding what I'm doing, works great too!

Comment: What I like of this answer is that not only restrict me only detecting the underscore (_) as a separator but any other alphanumeric character. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are looking for, the following will perform the match.  The non-capturing group is specified in the parens with `(?:...)`.  It is similar to the OP but also includes beginning and end-of-line anchors.

```
(?:^|\s|_)ra(?:$|\s|_)
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, this work perfectly! as with Tim Pietzcker's answer, thank to both!